# Clone window across all screens

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multiple-monitors

I'm using dualview setup in my OS (1 view extended across 2 screens). In my winforms application I can move particular window to secondary screen, e.g.:

```
foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    if (!s.Primary) {
        myform.Bounds = s.Bounds;
        break;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, when I can see this secondary screen. If I see it, I'm able to use any functionality such window form provides, e.g. I can close it by clicking the appropriate button.

But what if I cannot see this secondary screen, e.g. this is a projected image displayed on a wall in another room ? I cannot use my forsaken form then. How to cope with such uncomfortable situation (moving to the same room is not an option) ?

What I want is to make an exact duplicate of such form to be shown both on my primary screen and the secondary one. I'd really like to have multiple instances of the same window, exact copy, where one instance reflects changes at the other one and and vice versa. I could control the secondary screen (react on some popup information, etc) using the main one placed in remote location. I have no idea how to implement something like this in .Net with the usage of winforms. How to do it ?

BTW: If this is hard to achieve, what can be done from the conceptual point of view ? I know I can define some keyboard shortcuts but this is not what I'd like to have. Any ideas?

Comment: A Window has a handle. Duplicating that handle (and all handles it contains) would be problematic. How about, instead, create a "meta" list of windows that is displayed on your primary screen with a link to the form that's on the unseen screen. That way you can control it by sending it commands via your meta application.

Comment: I assume that using the Windows Display Settings to "Duplicate" displays (http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/twomonitors.aspx#fbid=8FUzom9Mh1T) is out of the question, right?

Comment: @Michael Todd: nice suggestion, if you have any more information of similar approaches I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @scott: right, it's out of scope here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, you could use a second window (call it a "Mirror form") to duplicate the primary form.  [Capture the screen for the primary form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx) and display the captured portion on the mirror form.

That part is the easy part. If you want to be able to actually interact with the Mirror form, you'll need to capture all user input such as mouse move, hover, click events, and keyboard events and replay them onto the main form.

You might be able to do that with the event handlers on the Mirror form by capturing all of them and replaying them them on the primary form. However, I'd look into capturing the messages on the mirror form. That is probably more comprehensive and probably a cleaner way code wise to "monitor" the events and send them over to the primary form. You can also "eat" messages going to the mirror form that would cause focus to change (e.g. there may be an issue if input focus suddenly shifts from the primary form to the mirror form while the user thinks they're interacting with the primary form).

For more info on Messages look into overriding then [WndProc of the Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc.aspx) (which is really [Control.WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx)) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28VS.85%29.aspx#windows_messages). A nice overview article is [Deliver The Power Of Spy++ To Windows Forms With Our New Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx). It also deals with cross-process communication which isn't relevant but explains a lot of the detail on messages and intercepting them.

Comment: Thanks for your effort (+1). I'll go through it tomorrow as it's the middle of the night in Poland right now.

Comment: The "Mirror form" (snapshot) approach is really smart, as I don't predict the audience to interact with the projected form. However there will be 2 issues related to that. The first one is reaction for changes made to the original form. As such form is interactive - something is being painted there as times goes by, the snapshot window should reflect these changes. Ideally - detect only the squares on which something has changed. The second thing - resolution. Cloning 1:1 doesn't allow to use different resolutions for projector and laptop (which is quite common thing).

Comment: I'm considering right now the creation of separated window (simple control panel, at the operator side), to control invisible projected window. These windows will be coupled. Control window is going to have reference to projected one and vice versa - if someone will close one of such windows, the second one will be closed either. Only minor required functionality will be implemented to the control panel (status changes, close button, etc). The full "cloning" seems to be quite big overhead.. (despite the fact it would be cool after all).

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko To update the snapshot on changes, you can respond to the correct windows messages. WM_PAINT if I recall correctly on any window/hwnd that is needed to repaint itself. So just detect those in the WndProc and trigger an update. Resolution will require a bit more thought, but I think you can deal with that by redrawing the window onto a different hDC/graphics device that has a different resolution. For a quick & easy hack (albeit lower quality image) I'd first play with just scaling the image. For a business app window it might be acceptable.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko I think the "operator window" approach (similar to the first part of my answer about the "Mirror form") is a solid approach. Definitely the biggest bang for the buck. As I went on to explain in my answer (after "the easy part") you can probably do the full clone but it will require a lot more effort on implementation and testing. SO I think the operator window approach is a good approach.